# Socket IO emitting multiple times (equal to number of clients connected) using sails js

Tags: node.js, socket.io, sails.js

I am trying to develop a simple socket io based chat app using sails MVC.
whenever a client connected socket emitting multiple times(equa to number of clients).
here is my code.

Server :

```
io=req.socket.manager;
var users=[];

io.sockets.on('connection', function(client) {
    console.log("connected");

    users.push(client.id);
    client.on("chat", function(data) {
        io.sockets.sockets[data.to].emit("chat", { from: client.id, to: data.to, msg: data.msg });
        client.emit("chat", { from: client.id, to: data.to, msg: data.msg });
    });
});
```

Client :

```
var socket=new io.connect('http://localhost:1337/');
socket.request('/Chat/index');
socket.emit('connection',function(data){
    console.log(data);
});
socket.on('connect', function() {
    console.log("Connected.");
    //
});
socket.on('chat', function(data) {
    console.log(data.msg );
});
```

please help me , is there any way to get actual socket object in sails?
I am using io=req.socket.manager; which is of req object.

Answer (score 0):

the socket object should be accessible in sails.io on the server side

[link](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-wiki/blob/0.9/sockets.md#still-need-more-control)

Comment: Hmm...i think that is not the problem,actually above code is inside a function call (req,res)...so everytime when i make a new request,it is adding to even listener,it is emitting as many times as no of clients.but i did not found a way to solve this

Answer (score 0):

maybe you want to answer to a unique `socket id`? that can be achieved this way:

In the file `sockets.js`, at your `config` folder, find the `onConnect` property and add code like this:

```
onConnect: function(session, socket){

    sails.io.sockets.socket(socket.id).send('YOUR_EVENT', {'message' : 'your message to a unique socket'}); 
    }
```

It will send a unique message when a new connection is established. Just a couple of notes:

- This can be considered a socket.io issue, not a sails issue, since the method .socket(socket.id) is part of socket.io
- This was tested on sails v0.9.8, in other versions the file sockets.js might not be included in the default generated app with sails' `new` command
- This is just an example to show how can it be done, you might need to adapt it to your needs.

Hope this helps.